# How can I use docker inside ubuntu container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I have an application that works on ubuntu 18.04 and requires docker.
This application has cli, and I can start it from command line, but to run this application, docker should be running.

I need to create docker image that runs this application.

I created a dockerfile, but I couldn't do what I want. Could you please check it and tell me what is wrong?

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt update
RUN apt install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common -y
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y

CMD ["service", "docker" ,"start"]
```

Comment: Could you add information about what goes wrong when you try this approach? That helps the community help you. (For what it's worth, it is typically challenging to run Docker inside Docker - it can be done but often leads to serious headaches. If you're sure you need to do it, that's ok, but be careful!)

Comment: For a couple of reasons, commands like `service` or `systemctl` don't really work inside Docker; you should directly run whatever program it is you want to run as the single foreground process the container runs.  As @SaraSinback notes, if that's a second Docker daemon, that's tricky, and it might be better to launch your container-managing process outside Docker or otherwise using the host's Docker socket.